# Overlaying matricies

Tags: excel

I have a several dozen grids in Excel like the one in the image below. I want to count the incidence of 'F' at each grid location and SUM it all in one new grid that I can contour plot. And then I'd like to automate so as I add new grids the cumulative grid captures the new data.

Thanks in advance for your good input.

Scott

[image]

Comment: I think you are going to need to share more of what your data looks like then that one picture. That being said, in your new grid in the first cell you could count up that first cell = F for every other grid kind of like `=(B1="F")+(B40="F")+(B72="F")...`  ASsuming that the same cell in your other grids is `b1`, `b40`, `b72`. Just keep stringing them together until you've accounted for that cell in every grid and you'll have your count. Then just copy and paste across that entire counting grid and your golden.

Comment: Do you have a grid in each sheet? Or everything is in one sheet?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(B2:O9,"=F")` ?   If you're just looking to count the occurances of "F" (and if your example matrix is in the range `B2:O9`).

Comment: Thanks all, not sure of the best way to communicate more data.  The worksheet I have has about thirty of the grids in the picture.  I want to create a cumulative grid that sums each cell for all the grids I'm monitoring, yes all the grids are in one worksheet, I tried the SUMIF function.  By holding down the Ctrl key and mouse selecting each grid I thought I could get all the grids into the this functions range.  A "too many cells selected error" happens even when I pare it down to just two grids.

Comment: I'm going to try the CountIF, thanks for that Peter.

Comment: COUNTIF works the same as this IF statement : =IF(Range = "F",1,0). That's good for one grid I get stuck trying to add more grids.

Comment: Hi JNevill,  Great solution but it looks like there is a limit on how many cells you can string together. Or the limit is in the number of characters.  Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Here's the string (Excel seems to limit any more entries): =('Image performance'!C7="F")+('Image performance'!C20="F")+('Image performance'!C33 = "F")+('Image performance'!C46="F")+('Image performance'!C59="F")+('Image performance'!C72="F")+('Image performance'!C86="F")+('Image performance'!C99="F")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this as long as your grids are regularly spaced one above the other.

Here "6" is the row offset of each grid from the previous one.

Adjust the ranges (ie. increase the "B3:B100")  to include any new data you might add.

It's an array formula, so use Ctrl+Shift+Enter for (eg) G3 then drag down/over

[image]